# why using Array instead of Dictionary in AS3 puremvc

Tags: actionscript-3

The as3 puremvc framework contains Controller, Model, View, they all in core folder.
The Controller class has commandMap that is Array type, the same as proxyMap in Model, mediaMap in View.
I don't know why they are Array, why not use Dictionary type?
I just to know benefit to using Array here? 
I would not going to debate whatnot.

Comment: -1 because this just asks for opinion and is likely to start debate. There's no specific programming problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been an `Object` or `Vector` too. You can make such decisions based on readability, performance or other reasons. However generally said, an `Array` in Actionsript 3 has good performance. I guess (hope) the team benchmarked the performance of all options, and the Array resulted as best performance.

If your interested in this topic, there are nice detailed performance tests over here:
http://jacksondunstan.com/?s=array+dictionary+performance

Since I'm not sure of all this, I challenge you to benchmark yourself, and maybe give a suggestion to the team.

Comment: I would vote you, but my vote less than 15. so sorry!

Comment: I think if you take some more time to answer or on the question you get easier upvotes. Always mention what youve tried yourself, what research you did, where your stuck etc. On answers, use links, correct spelling, point to alternative options and dont randomly say something. In this question its not completely clear what the exact question/point is, its very open.

Comment: thanks! my english is so bad. it's hard to express my question. I will try my hard.